# Why do all pages open in the default browser instead of inside the form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-xp, webbrowser-control

### What I Expect to Happen

The webpage opens inside the form.

[image: Expected]

### What Really Happens

The webpage opens in the default browser (in this case Chrome).

[image: Issue]

### The Code

The `Navigate(string)` snippet is copied directly from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161352%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
  using System;
  using System.Windows.Forms;

  namespace BrowserFrame
  {
      public partial class BrowserForm: Form
      {
          public BrowserForm()
          {
              InitializeComponent();
              Navigate("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
          }

          private void Navigate(String address)
          {
              if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(address)) return;
              if (address.Equals("about:blank")) return;
              if (!address.StartsWith("http://") &&
                  !address.StartsWith("https://"))
              {
                  address = "http://" + address;
              }
              try
              {
                  webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri(address));
              }
              catch (System.UriFormatException)
              {
                  return;
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

### What I Did So Far

- Changing the default browser (e.g. IE, Firefox) opens the page in the default browser.
- Using `webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.stackoverflow.com"));` directly does the same thing.
- Tried calling Navigate from other events (e.g. OnLoad, MouseClick); same result.

### Update

- Turns out this happens to *all* web-based UI controls. (Posted [a question on superuser.](https://superuser.com/questions/772600/why-do-all-web-based-ui-open-in-the-default-browser-instead-of-inside-the-window))

Comment: I have tried your code and it works correctly. What exactly is your problem? Did you mean that the page are opened in Browser on your computer instead in webBrowser control of the Form?

Comment: Try to call Navigate method from another place, not from the Constructor. Call it from OnLoad event handler

Comment: @Lev Added your suggestions in "What I Did So Far", still doesn't work. I think something is wrong with my OS settings. (Todo: Try on another computer.)

Comment: But what is happening? The page is opening in the computer's browser and not in webBrowser control?

Comment: @Lev Yes. I asked [this question on superuser](http://superuser.com/questions/772600/why-do-all-web-based-ui-open-in-the-default-browser-instead-of-inside-the-window) since I found out that all web-based controls are affected and not just in WinForms.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why it would open in an external browser, as it doesn't happen to me, but you can try this and see if it makes any difference.

Have you tried:

`webBrowser1.Navigate(address);` without using an Uri?

It works fine for me, and it doesn't need `http://` or `https://`.

I guess they automated that in the class constructor for strings.

Or perhaps you could try changing to this simple version:

```
public BrowserForm()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
}
```

Just to see if it helps.